# Using associative PHP array in JS to later on use in chart generated via chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I'm using chart.js to display charts I have associative array in PHP that I would like use as data for my line chart.

Here is var_dump of how the table looks like http://i.imgur.com/GBO5S1o.png
So label would be SEASON 3 SEASON 2 SEASON 1
and buffseason for SEASON 3 would be in $Patch->season['Season 3']['buff'] and so on I don't really know how to translate those values to JS and below is what I've tried array_keys which did not work probably because it should be foreach loop with => $key

```
<script>
var labels = <?php echo array_keys($Patch->season); ?>;
var buffseason = <?php echo $Patch->season; ?>;
var nerfseason = <?php echo $Patch->season; ?>;
nerfseason.reverse();
labels.reverse();
buffseason.reverse();

var lineData = {
    labels,
    datasets : [
        {

            label: "Buffs",
            fillColor : "rgba(128, 222, 87, 0.4)",
            strokeColor : "#80DE57",
            pointColor : "#80DE57",
            pointStrokeColor : "#80DE57",
            data: buffseason
        },
        {
            label: "Nerfs",
            fillColor : "rgba(222, 91, 84,0.4)",
            strokeColor : "#DE5B54",
            pointColor : "#DE5B54",
            pointStrokeColor : "red",
            data : nerfseason
        }
    ]
}
 var change_line = document.getElementById('change_line').getContext('2d');
    new Chart(change_line).Line(lineData)
</script>
```

Comment: Get your array in the correct structure then simply `json_encode()` it

Comment: @Scuzzy Could you elaborate what do you mean by correct structure?

Comment: As you've hinted at with a foreach loop, you're going to need to loop over your data and start preparing it into an array structure that matches your expected javascript output. From there you'll be able to perform `var buffseason = <?php echo json_encode($Patch->season); ?>;` on your data. There are plenty of resources out there on php array/object building, it's fundamental knowledge to using PHP.

Comment: @Scuzzy Well I thought there would be an easier version in javascript that wouldn't multiplicate my code but I guess not.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the correct structure in javascript itself, like so

```
// it's not good to rely on reverse() because we are using an ASSOCIATIVE array
// so we get the object's keys and sort them
var labels = Object.keys(input).sort(function (a, b) {
    // the substring removes the 'SEASON ' part
    // i.e. we sort by the numeric part
    return a.substring(7) - b.substring(7);
});
// pick the buff elements in the same order as the labels
var buffseason = labels.map(function (e) {
    return input[e].buff;
});
// pick the buff elements in the same order as the labels
var nerfseason = labels.map(function (e) {
    return input[e].nerf;
})

var lineData = {
    ...
```

where `input` is your JSON encoded associative array, i.e. something like

```
{
    'SEASON 3': {
        'nerf': 0,
        'buff': 2
    },
    'SEASON 2': {
        'nerf': 5,
        'buff': 2
    },
    'SEASON 1': {
        'nerf': 9,
        'buff': 20
    }
}
```